# What would be the most efficient way of doing something like this?

Tags: android

So I want to create an app that has a list of things, but when you click on one of the things in the list, a whole new page is displayed showing information on the price of the object in the list.

This is list would have over 100 things on it, would need to have a different image beside each one, and would need to have the ability to add things into the list(because its going to be alphabetical).

I'm not really asking for the code on how to make this happen, but more the battle plan on how to make this happen, so like "Use a ListView here, and then here do this, etc". 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the FAQ on what questions can be asked here. Stackoverflow is not a discussion forum. We do solve specific programming related problems which have a specific answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you'll primarily be dealing with two activities, one for your list of items and one for displaying the details of the object.

**Object List Activity**

You'll probably want your activity to use a [ListFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html) to load all of the objects. You can then create your own adapter subclass of [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) and load all of your data into it so you can create each view for the `ListFragment`. Once you've created the adapter you can use the [setListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html#setListAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)) method to set the `ListFragment`'s adapter and start loading the data you have in the adapter.

**Adding New Items**

If you want to add new items you will probably want to create a menu with `onCreateOptionsMenu` in your `ListFragment` with something like a plus button as the icon. When `onOptionsItemSelected` is called you can start a [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) to give the user the option to add new items.

Once the user has added an item in the `DialogFragment` and save the data somewhere such as your SqliteDatabase. Once the `DialogFragment` has returns to the ListActivity you should update your adapter with the newly added item as well as call `getListView().notifyDatasetChanged()` in the `ListFragment`.

**Object Detail Activity**

This should be pretty simple. When the `ListFragment` gets a callback from `onListItemClicked` simply pass this data through an `Intent` and start a new `Activity` to handle displaying the details of the object clicked

Answer (score 0):

You should use those things:

1. ListView
2. ArrayAdapter<>
3. FragmentActivity
4. Custom Dialog

Because you are going to have over 100 elements on it, it's good idea to let Android (ListView) handle memory stuff. I mean, it's going to reuse cell/arrow/view from the list to avoid memory abuse.

With ArrayAdapter you can handle the "add/update" listView and customize all you want. You should use another FragmentActivity/Dialog for new values for "add" process.

FragmentActivity is just a preference of me because compatibility with Android's version